# How to GET reCAPTCHA picture address?

Tags: c#, recaptcha

This is my idea:

1. I get this address from source, for example: `http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Lc_Wb0SAAAAAPpDWSnsxg7rFxSJT46Wmic3Ximb`
2. Then I get "challenge" from this site, for example: `challenge : '03AHJ_VuumDpsD-dz-rSeL_Vyd5fUqHMJLNtlpiyaEq0RzDhsaNTWTydaOcYk5cdRX55C6VyaojWJwCa6T6PF8LF4Io5NUC09Kj0HRNczh9tJXBsrx26BcfBtrwvPabvbR_SnJXdmc9YS2L76PqI9EdtfXPhhCV9V2jw'`
3. Then I get address of picture, for example: `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuumDpsD-dz-rSeL_Vyd5fUqHMJLNtlpiyaEq0RzDhsaNTWTydaOcYk5cdRX55C6VyaojWJwCa6T6PF8LF4Io5NUC09Kj0HRNczh9tJXBsrx26BcfBtrwvPabvbR_SnJXdmc9YS2L76PqI9EdtfXPhhCV9V2jw`

But there is a problem - pic is other than I have to write. Can you tell me how I can get oryginal address?

Answer (score 1):

If the image you get doesn't match up with the one that you have to type then I'm guessing you aren't passing the same challenge code to the verification method of the api as to the image part.

It would help if you could paste a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the non-javascript API call output for how it actually gets fetched without all the javascript getting in the way, there wouldn't appear to be a reason your strategy would give the wrong image.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lc_Wb0SAAAAAPpDWSnsxg7rFxSJT46Wmic3Ximb

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Mike got the point you need to pass recaptcha_challenge_field=03AHJ_VuumDpsD-dz-rSeL_Vyd5fUqHMJLNtlpiyaEq0RzDhsaNTWTydaOcYk5cdRX55C6VyaojWJwCa6T6PF8LF4Io5NUC09Kj0HRNczh9tJXBsrx26BcfBtrwvPabvbR_SnJXdmc9YS2L76PqI9EdtfXPhhCV9V2jw