# Get re-Captha image and submit form

Tags: recaptcha

Is it possible to get recaptcha images from a non-web application?

For example, I'd like to show an image (for example in jdownload), and submit text and see result in python or java?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here? did you want to use reCaptcha within a (non-web) application?

Comment: I would be able to read the recaptcha images from a non-web application example jdownload :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to GET reCAPTCHA picture address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532157/how-to-get-recaptcha-picture-address)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Since recaptcha works over normal HTTP, you will need to have your java or python application simulate the same calls.

Comment: Thanks but in html don't see image url because is generated by javascript ... this is my problem

Comment: Use a normal browser and determine what the sending URL is. You likely will need to duplicate the logic that is inside the javascript, since recaptcha uses encryption to avoid security risks.